# What is different VOID & DYNAMIC function in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Dynamic myName function**

```dart
void main(){
 myName(nik:121);
}

dynamic myName({String? firstName, String lastName = 'Tono', required int nik}) {
  print(nik);
  print(lastName);
  print(firstName);
}
```

**Void myName function**

```dart
void main(){
 myName(nik:121);
}

void myName({String? firstName, String lastName = 'Tono', required int nik}) {
  print(nik);
  print(lastName);
  print(firstName);
}
```

is it any differnt between void and dynamic function in dart language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: **void means nothing and dynamic means anything.**

This means, a void function can't return anything. You can try and you will get an error in your IDE.
A dynamic function can return anything, "void " included.
Try it by returning a string or a double or a list, everything is allowed.

However, usually a function should not return dynamic. It should serve a single purpose and if it returns something (or nothing), the return type should be defined.

In your example, I'd use void as your function does not return anything.